# Get a reference to insert rows with triggers

Tags: sql, db2, sql-insert

I'm trying to get a reference to a set of rows that I'm trying to insert into a table through a multiple insert. For example if I execute:

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES (0,'A'),(1,'B'),(2,'C')
```

I would like to get a reference in a *before insert trigger* to a "table" that contains these 3 rows. Is that possible?
And another question: what does a REFERENCING NEW_TABLE represents in a before trigger (maybe could this be the answer to the first question)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-94):

> **REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS identifier**
>       Specifies a temporary table name which identifies the affected rows as modified by the triggering SQL operation and by any SET
>   statement in a BEFORE trigger that has already executed.

Also take a look:

> **FOR EACH STATEMENT**
>       Specifies that the triggered action is to be applied only once for the whole statement. This type of trigger granularity cannot be
>   specified for a BEFORE trigger or an INSTEAD OF trigger (SQLSTATE
>   42613). If specified, an UPDATE or DELETE trigger is activated, even
>   if no rows are affected by the triggering UPDATE or DELETE statement.

maybe it will suite better your needs (of course you need to go with AFTER trigger)